# Code Runs Only If Visual Basic Editor is Open

Tags: excel, vba, circular-reference

I have a really weird problem about VBA.
I tried to list circular references at activeworkbook and i have written below code for that. It only works if i press ALT+F11. So if VBA Editor window is open, code runs correctly but otherwise it is not working.
By the way, code is in a module at Addin and i call it from ribbon. You may see the code below.
Your help is highly appreciated. Bruteforce solution works. I hope someone can find decent solution than me.

```
Type SaveRangeCir
    Val As Variant
    Addr As String
    Preaddress As String
    Shtname As String
    Workbname As String
End Type
Public OldCir() As SaveRangeCir
Sub DonguselBasvurulariBul(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim wba As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim dummy As Worksheet
Dim Item As Range
Dim crcell As Range
Dim cll As Range

un = "Sayin " & Environ("UserName")

muyarcirc = MsgBox("Lutfen Oncelikle Dosyanizi Kaydedin" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
"-->> Dosyanizi Kaydettiniz mi?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, un)

If muyarcirc = vbno Then
    muyar2 = MsgBox("Dongusel Basvuru Arama Islemi Iptal Edildi", vbInformation, un)
    Exit Sub
End If

'BruteForce Solution
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False

    .VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
    .Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    .VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
End With

On Error Resume Next

Set wba = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsa = wba.ActiveSheet

wba.Worksheets.Add

Set dummy = ActiveSheet

For Each sht2 In wba.Sheets
    If sht2.Name = "Dongusel Basvurular" Then
        sht2.Delete
    End If
Next sht2

wba.Worksheets.Add

Set ws = wba.ActiveSheet

dummy.Delete

With ws
    .Name = "Dongusel Basvurular"
    .Range("A1") = "Dongusel Basvuru Hucresi"
    .Range("B1") = "Dongusel Basvuru Hucresi Formul Degeri"
    .Range("C1") = "Bagli Oldugu Alan"
    .Range("D1") = "Bulundugu Sayfa"
    .Range("E1") = "Bulundugu Dosya"
End With

With wba
    For Each sht In .Worksheets
        If sht.CodeName <> ws.CodeName Then
            sht.Activate
            crcell = Nothing

        Do
            Set crcell = sht.CircularReference

            If Not crcell Is Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve OldCir(1 To crcell.Precedents.Cells.Count)

                i = 0
                For Each cll In crcell.Precedents
                    i = i + 1
                    OldCir(i).Addr = cll.Address
                    OldCir(i).Val = cll.Formula
                    OldCir(i).Preaddress = cll.Precedents.Address
                    OldCir(i).Shtname = cll.Parent.Name
                    OldCir(i).Workbname = cll.Parent.Parent.Name
                    cll.Value = cll.Value
                Next cll
                For j = LBound(OldCir) To UBound(OldCir)
                    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    ws.Cells(lr, 1) = OldCir(j).Addr
                    ws.Cells(lr, 2) = "'" & OldCir(j).Val
                    ws.Cells(lr, 3) = OldCir(j).Preaddress
                    ws.Cells(lr, 4) = OldCir(j).Shtname
                    ws.Cells(lr, 5) = OldCir(j).Workbname
                    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(lr, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Cells(lr, 4) & "!" & ws.Cells(lr, 1), _
                    ScreenTip:="Dongusel Basvuru Hucresini Gormek icin Tiklayiniz"
                Next j
            Else
                GoTo skipsheet
            End If

            Erase OldCir
            Set crcell = sht.CircularReference

        Loop While crcell.Cells.Count > 0

        lr2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For m = 2 To lr2
            If ActiveSheet.Name <> ws.Cells(lr2, "D") Then
                wba.Sheets(ws.Cells(m, "D")).Activate
            End If
            Range(ws.Cells(m, 1)).Formula = "=" & Right(ws.Cells(m, 2), Len(ws.Cells(m, 2)) - 1)
        Next m
    End If
skipsheet:
Next sht

If ws.Range("A2") = "" Then
    ws.Delete
    wsa.Activate
    m1 = MsgBox("Aktif Dosyada Dongusel Basvuru Bulunamadi", vbInformation, "Sayin " & Environ("UserName"))
Else
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1:E1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End If
End With

Erase OldCir
Set crcell = Nothing

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` hides all error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. You can't fix your errors if you don't see them. Remove that line and fix your errors! • Additionally I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. •  After that I recommend to read [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) in case you need to implement a good error handling.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Doesn't run at all, doesn't do what it should, causes an error, or something else?

Comment: Actually i tried to avoid errors while setting the circular references. Thats why i am using on error resume next statement. My problem is if i open VBA Editor window i get results which is a list of circular references but if VBA Editor is not opened there is no list at same workbook. I would like to give extra information. Code sits in an encrypted module in addin. thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks Rory for your help. Actually code runs well but i received different result whether VBA Editor window is visible or not

Comment: `Worksheets.Add` does the first one need to reference a workbook if called in the addin?

Comment: You still shouldn't just put OERN at the top of the code and then hope for the best. Use it only for the time required and then reset error handling as soon as you can. Also, you need to be specific as to what the "different results" are, and where in the add-in the code is located.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I appreciatd. After i change my code based on your suggestions. Problem is still going on. If i call my code from ribbon without open VBA Editor,  i can't get the circular references list but if i open VBA EDitor with ALT+F11 and call code from ribbon again, i get the list of circular references list. My code is in a encrypted module of my Addin which locates at C:\Users\M_C*******\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns . Your suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem using VBA in MS Access. I understand you are using VBA Excel but I thought I'd post my personal experience in case it helps.

I have an Access form with a button that opens another form. The button is coded with VBA. If the VBA Editor was not open when I clicked the button then the new form would open but Form_Load() wouldn't trigger. If the VBA editor was open when I clicked the button then Form_Load() triggered as intended.

I did not have On Error Resume Next hiding any errors and all my variables were set with Option Explicit.

To troubleshoot the issue, I added a number of msgboxes throughout the code to narrow down where the problem was occurring.   After adding a msgbox to the Click() event of the button I realized that the connection was somehow re-established and the code no longer needed the VBA editor open. After realizing this, I deleted the msgbox from the code, closed the application, re-opened the application without the VBA editor and from then on the VBA executed as intended.

Unfortunately, I came upon a solution while troubleshooting so I cannot provide an explanation as to why this worked but sometimes an explanation is not needed as long as you get it working again!

Hope this helps.

Comment: at which part, the connection was lost? can you give me a specific event when connection reestablished. Maybe there is another event to trigger the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

However, it appeared have been caused by first using a message box with no return variable, then extending it to include a return, ie ret = msgbox(

Deleted the message box, code worked, closed and saved the project, reopened and message box with return variable added and now it run even without the editor open.